# Double click file to open in running instance of FMX app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When a file is double-clicked, I want it to open in the running instance of my Firemonkey app. For the moment, I am just trying to get the code working in Win32 but ultimately I want similar behavior in OSX.

I have the following code in my .dpr. I found the part relating to the mutex on https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=873440 and it works fine in suppressing the opening of a second instance.

```
var
  OneInstanceMutex: THandle = 0;
  MessageManager: TMessageManager;
  Message: TMessage;

function InstanceAlreadyExists(const MutexName: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  // .. This mutex will be freed when the application closes!
  OneInstanceMutex := CreateMutex (nil, FALSE, PChar(MutexName) );
  if OneInstanceMutex <> 0 then
  begin
    if GetLastError() = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then
    begin
    // Found another instance
    Result := True;
  end;
end 
else
begin
   if GetLastError() = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED then
   begin
     // Found another instance
     Result := True;
   end;
  end;
end;

begin
if InstanceAlreadyExists('MyApp.exe') then
begin
  MessageManager := TMessageManager.DefaultManager;
  Message := TMessage<UnicodeString>.Create(ParamStr(1));
  MessageManager.SendMessage(nil, Message, True);
  Exit;
end;
Application.Initialize;
```

In the main form, in the FormCreate event, I have

```
procedure TMyMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SubscriptionId: Integer;
  MessageManager: TMessageManager;
begin
....
MessageManager := TMessageManager.DefaultManager;
SubscriptionId := MessageManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessage<UnicodeString>,
  procedure(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage)
  begin
    ShowMessage((M as TMessage<UnicodeString>).Value);
  end);
// I'm expecting the above to show the filename to be opened
// but no message appears
....
end;
```

With one instance already running, when I double-clicking on a file, I'm expecting the line

```
    ShowMessage((M as TMessage<UnicodeString>).Value);
```

to display the filename to be opened but no message appears.

BTW, I have correctly associated the file extension with my app so that the .dpr is receiving ParamStr(1). It's just that the broadcasting of this string to the already running instance isn't working.